# TrueCrypt: NTFS or FAT?

Tags: security, filesystems, truecrypt

The default file system for a TrueCrypt volume is FAT.  Isn't NTFS more robust?  What are the pros and cons of creating a TrueCrypt NTFS vs. FAT volume?

Comment: If you don't specifically need NTFS for something like permissions, use FAT.

Answer (score 7):

NTFS is more robust as filesystems go, but isn't supported as well on non-Windows operating systems. If the volume you want to create will be on portable media and used on a number of different machines, FAT32 overall will be easier to manage. It mainly comes down to a question of convenience.

Comment: Would you suggest NTFS for a Windows-only drive?

Comment: If you know you're only going to use it under Windows, then yes, NTFS would be my choice. Especially if you're talking about a drive that's going to be more than a few gigabytes in size.

Comment: Still you can read or even write NTFS drives depending on operating system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Interoperability

Answer (score 2):

If you are **only** going to use the partition under **Windows**, NTFS would be my choice.

- One drawback is using FAT [limits the **file size**](http://forums.anandtech.com/archive/index.php/t-1664093.html) although TrueCrypt seems able to use [exFAT with larger files](https://superuser.com/questions/383326/truecrypt-large-files), but this may be [OS-dependent](http://www.rowanwatson.com/truecrypt-with-windows-7-and-os-x-lion-or-snow-leopard-with-large-file-support/). This could be relevant if you use big data on the drive (e.g. [SqlServer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627224)).
- Another consequence of a (TrueCrypt) FAT volume, is that symbolic links to a TrueCypt-FAT-partition from an NTFS-partition, will show a lock icon in Windows 7. This indicates [the FAT-folder does not inherit permissions from the parent folder](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/remove-lock-icon-on-folder-in-windows-7/). I assume the icon is limited to Windows 7, but the permissions-issue is not.

If you are going to use the partition on a **read-only medium** (CD, DVD), and one should be able to read it with **Windows 2000**, then FAT should be your choice:

- [VeraCrypt FAQ](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ) mentions “Windows 2000 cannot mount an NTFS file system on read-only media”. (Considering TrueCrypt’s detailed documentation, I assume this only applies to Windows 2000.)

Comment: Because TrueCrypt-development was stopped, its link was broken.  However, it has multiple successors, for which I assume the question and answer are still valid.  So I replaced the broken TrueCrypt-FAQ-link with a VeraCrypt-FAQ-link, which is one of the successors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using it with Dropbox, would suggest using NTFS.  I noticed some files would not download onto a Dropbox that was linked to a TrueCrypt drive formatted as FAT32.