# TrueCrypt - Large Files

Tags: macos, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, truecrypt

I am encrypting a USB drive with TrueCrypt. It asks me if I am going to store files larger than 4gb:

[image: TrueCrypt - Large Files]

Does this make any difference (apart from being able to store files larger than 4gb on the volume)? Why is this option here?

I'm on Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for compatibility with the FAT32 file system which has a file size limitation of `2^32 - 1 bytes`, which is equivalent to `4 GB - 1 byte`. These options let TrueCrypt manage it's container accordingly.